# How to insert NumberFormatException in the input part and display "Input error" if the user did not enter a number

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class numberformat {
    
    public void pw(int n, String ch) {
        
        String one[] = { " ", " One", " Two", " Three", " Four", " Five", " Six", " Seven", " Eight", " Nine", " Ten"};
        
        if (n<=10)
        {
            System.out.print(one[n]);
        }
        if (n > 0)
        
            System.out.print(ch);
            
    }
        
        
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int n = 0;
            Scanner scanf = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter an integer number: ");
            n = scanf.nextInt();
            
            if (n <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter numbers greater than 0");
            }
            else{
                numberformat a = new numberformat();
                a.pw((n / 1000000000), " Hundred");
                a.pw((n / 10000000) % 100, " billion");
                a.pw(((n / 100000) % 100), " million");
                a.pw(((n / 1000) % 100), " thousand");
                a.pw(((n / 100) % 10), " hundred");
                a.pw((n % 100), " ");
            }
        }
}
```

How to insert the `NumberFormatException` and display `Error`, if the user did not enter a number.

Comment: What do you mean by inserting exception and what error you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

Add a method for input because you have to re-enter the number if the number is not greater than zero:-

```
public static int inputs() {
        Scanner scanf = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        try {
                n = scanf.nextInt();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Input Error!");
            }
        return n;
    }
```

Edit in 'main' method:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
            int n = inputs();
        if (n <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter numbers greater than 0");
            n = inputs();
        }
        else {
            numberformat a = new numberformat();
            a.pw((n / 1000000000), " Hundred");
            a.pw((n / 10000000) % 100, " billion");
            a.pw(((n / 100000) % 100), " million");
            a.pw(((n / 1000) % 100), " thousand");
            a.pw(((n / 100) % 10), " hundred");
            a.pw((n % 100), " ");
        }
    }
```